# Compute formula by selecting the first and the last non-missing values in dynamic width in one column to fill in the NAs over the widith

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, width, return-value

I have data of two variables gert and NAV. I need to fill in the missing NAs of NAV variable. 
To compute those missing NAs, I need to use the first and last non-missing NAV values and the return values (gret) to do the imputation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93l2h.png)

the width between the two in red colored non-missing NAV values is n = 3, and the first and last non-missing values are 6830228.05 and 14277802.16

to impute the first missing NAV value (in this specific width) which has a return of -0.2, I do the following:

first and for each width n, I compute a factor called F, after that I use it over all NAs within this specific width n.

So, the value of the first missing NAV would be = **F * 6830228.05 * (1 - 0.2)**

The value that I imputed above, I use it then to impute the second missing NAV value which has a return of +1.58  and which would be = F * (**F * 6830228.05 * (1 - 0.2)**) * (1 + 1.58).

for the the third missing value, I do the same and I use the previous imputed NAV.

the formale of F for this width n = 3 is as following: (note: I use all values of return in this width to compute F and only I use the first and last non-missing NAV values)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9tw6.png)

I replicate this process by moving down to the second width n = 2 and for which, the first and last non-missing NAV values are 15030901.93 and 16911789.99 (colored green)

the formale of F for this width n = 2 is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRc0N.png)

and so on until the end of this variable series.

May someone help me please me in coding this in R?

Many thanks

Comment: Please kindly read the tag description in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r. *Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks instead.*

Comment: well noted! Thanks